# How set variation after filter in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

For simple example i have product "pen" with variation "black" and "red". After use filter "red" on shop page need to set appropriate variation on product (red).Or though set the appropriate picture after filter.

On my site activate theme - "Woodmart". In this theme filter works with pjax.

If have any idea or appropriate hooks, write it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I understand correctly that you want to filter them in woocommerce (products) by color - by clicking on the colored square? If so, here is the plugin you need.
[YITH WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/)

[DEMO](https://plugins.yithemes.com/yith-woocommerce-ajax-product-filter/)
[image]

Comment: I already have ajax filter on my site.
For example in your demo if i click on green round filter, i not see green photo (i see black) but i need green photo. It not work on my site too.

Comment: Ah, I understand you ... - So black remains because attribution with black color is present in the variants of the required goods ... If the attribute black is removed in a variable product, then only green ones will be shown ... Maybe you need to go differently ways and create products each color is a separate product. But in my opinion - it will be a long time.